# How to implemented a function returning with TypeMap return

Tags: typescript

I have a discriminate union type `Actions`. For each action, I have a different handler function, returning a different result.
I now need a generic handler function that based on `action.type` calls the respective handler function and returns its result. The type signature of this function should be such that TypeScript can infer the shape of the result based on the called parameter. I achieve this  with the type signature `const handler = <A extends Action>(a: A): HandlerMap[A['type']] => ...`. However, TypeScript complains in the implemented switch statement, that the return is invalid:

```
Type 'Result1' is not assignable to type 'HandlerMap[A["type"]]'.
  Type 'Result1' is not assignable to type 'Result1 & Result2'.
    Type 'Result1' is not assignable to type 'Result2'.
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Here's the full code:

```
type Action1 = { type: 'A1'; input: { i: string } }
type Result1 = { result: string }
const handler1 = (a: Action1): Result1 => ({ result: a.input.i + '!' })

type Action2 = { type: 'A2'; input: { x: number } }
type Result2 = { result: { r2: number } }
const handler2 = (a: Action2): Result2 => ({ result: { r2: a.input.x + 1 } })

type Action = Action1 | Action2

type HandlerMap = {
  A1: Result1
  A2: Result2
}

const handler = <A extends Action>(a: A): HandlerMap[A['type']] => {
  switch (a.type) {
    case 'A1':  return handler1(a) // <--Compiler complains here
    case 'A2':  return handler2(a)
    default:    return undefined
  }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using overloads instead if you do not have many actions to handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add this approach:

```
const handler = <A extends Action>(a: A): HandlerMap[A['type']] => {

  const map: { 
    [K in keyof HandlerMap]: (a: Extract<Action, { type: K }>) => HandlerMap[K] 
  } = {
    "A1": (a) => handler1(a),
    "A2": (a) => handler2(a),
  }

  return map[a.type](a as any) as HandlerMap[A["type"]]
}
```

We could replace the `switch` with an object called `map`. This object contains a key `K` for each `type` with a callback. The return type of this callback is strictly typed to be `HandlerMap[K]`.

Pros:

- `map` is exhaustive and will give a compile time error if you forget to handle a case
- the argument `a` in each callback is strictly typed to be the correct `Action` type. So doing something like `a.input.i` would be possible in the first callback
- the return type of the callback is strictly typed. So returning `handler1(a)` in the second callback would lead to a compile time error

Cons:

- we have to use `as any` in the return statement (thanks to the [correlated union issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581))
- we also have to use `as HandlerMap[A["type"]]` because of TypeScript's eager resolution of the `map[a.type]()` to `Result1 | Result2` instead of `{ "A1": ..., "A2": ... }[A["type"]](A)`.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYEYoF4oG8qiQBcUA5DOqQNxSKpgCuwJ%20iJAzsAE50DmUAX0EAoQtABKEdgwA2wTDnxcps5lE49U-AcLhpOUABYBDVABMZELgqgAKYyXhI06AJQlJ0uQoB8dpSpyJMYAdHSMwGFQANRkAISkgq7CouDQTiioAEzYeARpJORZ1LT0TCxQAB4kqAwAtgBGVoIiYlCeqjmKUMpeakpZNfVNXC06eqgGJuaWXF12DrAImVnu7YHAXX62AX0Vc8FhZZGVMVCYQgLJqZBLzqi5GS5QAD53KyltABKmFlYAssYwLlcMIoLB0B4NugwbBBus%20llhDpdPpgEZfrNcgAeGBQCCVYAQczsd5oHz2RxrH4zAFAgDaMHppDEpAAumzsH5QbCJgY6kCKrDwfSANKlKAAawgIGQADMoDS-lxAWA2SRKVAAKKErjGBC45ZoAA0eTEJHFAh8ri5isxdLAYs5sKEimFUAARBQPRrjDasH5psr0PZXMb3V6sj6Fv7A-a5qHw%20CUeDlMAGFwHgLHaExGz7FBjKTTCAbUW7bSVQymR6xB6OcigA)

Answer (score 2):

You can actually circumvent the type checker for the function signature by moving the function signature into an overload:

```
function handler<A extends Action>(a: A): HandlerMap[A['type']];
function handler(a: Action) {
    switch (a.type) {
        case 'A1':  return handler1(a);
        case 'A2':  return handler2(a);
        default:    return undefined;
    }
}
```

Then TypeScript thinks the type of `handler` (inside the body of `handler`, at least) is `handler(a: Action): ???` and it will infer the type for you.
However, this doesn't mean you won't get the typings you originally wanted!

Because of the external function signature `handler<A extends Action>(a: A): HandlerMap[A['type']]`, you still retain the original behavior.

Below, when you hover over `handler`, you'll actually see this signature from TypeScript, instead of `handler(a: Action): ???`.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXjE8m)

Comment: Thanks! While that works, the type checking is still incomplete: E.g. `case 'A1':  return null` is clearly wrong, but TS does not complain. Ideally anything returned by the `A1` branch should be checked to be `Result1`...

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error in your code, it says `Type 'Result2' is not assignable to type 'Result1 & Result2'`.

The `Result1 & Result2` part here is suspicious. What you really need is `Result1 | Result2`. So you can provide the function a return type exactly like you need:

```
type Results = Result1 | Result2

const handler = <A extends Action>(a: A): Results => {
  switch (a.type) {
    case 'A1':  return handler1(a);
    case 'A2':  return handler2(a);
  }
}
```

Do note that the relation in this type of Action1 -> Result 1 is not very strongly typed. This relation is only ensured in the definition of your handlers. The return type of any of the `handlers` can be from any of the `Results`

For example, you may have a handler defined like the following and it will still work for the case 'A2':

```
const handler3 = (a: Action2): Result1 => ({ result: a.input.x + '!' })
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=37&ssc=72&pln=37&pc=1#code/PQ18QsAUCAEBNA8gVQEpwMJICIFEskBZIvAOQBU8c5UKYJGmYHg4AXATwAcBTOAIIBjdgEsA9gDsAjHAC8cAN4cevAFxwA5AOmaA3HFGTuAV3YblojQGd2AJyMBzOAF9XrFXzhpe1kwBt2WQVlO18A8zhbB0lnFw8hKVs4AAsAQ0kAE39eO2C4AAo0jWExKWkASg0fP0DggD5C0PDAjTSAOiNTdk64AGotAEJNVwqWWDYuL1KJSQAmeSVPdS0BOf1DYzMLOAAPDUkTAFsAI1zXdwnl7xb2BZC4MNrI0LmD47O7C-irxMlk9JZHJ2e6FYqCESzOZVG7Pe6NArNZ47EFtTpbHq7fpwWRuFxjaAeKb8GZSRakmRwAA%20ELK83G8GJcAAEhlsrkiGluItFB44IJpNVbtI%20YI3rCInMPD8Ekl2Kk2cDFgAeARwXi7di8LLWWmzepFEow1lAjlcgDaAnNmmJmgAunb5I1eVd%20dYAO6idhCFJg9rEipKUX8oRpaz8bS6DSPXjsEx2SQK015IqB%20DKgC0Gcw4iO3FESsSef8aSMupSuV4wbgofDq3W0bCcYTSfZINT1cyvAAZmkItH%20U344mTFke0ZeJlRT94DLCdAmRT8spiRpIxsutsllYovYnN8YEyahFlzHkbuYnEYH8AYrcvlDXryjDj3UnU0z-24B1Nz1RNjNGGUZxkXSEpFBFdVDXNYNwxHZ9jgQ5TnOPFD1UCVAggz9WiWVFEI%20FDLhveVATbUFHwpaEhThd9EWwl5HnFH8MXaLEBlxYD52I1tgQAZkWCiwPmF9hVopEv2Y7pWIAoD8RA9CKXJITZBpSj5K8V92F1BRNJUjC7nGbjSKVBRVXVTVtUyXUKQNcEBBE55tOdGA3U9b1fSKf1VEDF1%20RDMMIx0TRG1jYcePvVMDHTLMczzAtziLbgSzLVJKxcvza0ChtB1CltjNyOZIvSn4fiAA)

Comment: But then you lose the relation of the action type to the return type, which I think OP wants to preserve.

Comment: Yeah. I did mention that in the note. That is only ensured by the definition of the handler but might be workable for the OP if he is okay with it. Probably not an ideal solution, I agree