# Typescript is throwing an error when I use generic

Tags: typescript

This is basic sample code.
I have tried to create a Factory method which can make a specific class by concrete Enum value but when I have tried to make a specific class the typescript displayed me an error
Basically the ConcreateSettings[SettingsEnum.A] must be the same as SettingsA but the TS doesn't understand it or I am wrong

After executing this code Typescript makes an error

```
enum SettingsEnum {
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B',
    C = 'C',
}

type SettingsA = {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    width: number;
    height: number;
};

type SettingsB = {
    r1: number;
    r2: number;
};

type SettingsC = {
    text: string;
};

type ConcreateSettings = {
    [SettingsEnum.A]: SettingsA;
    [SettingsEnum.B]: SettingsB;
    [SettingsEnum.C]: SettingsC;
};

interface SettingsInterface<T extends Record<string, unknown>> {
    getSettings(): T;
}

class A implements SettingsInterface<SettingsA> {
    getSettings(): SettingsA {
        return {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
        };
    }
}

class B implements SettingsInterface<SettingsB> {
    getSettings(): SettingsB {
        return {
            r1: 0,
            r2: 0,
        };
    }
}

class C implements SettingsInterface<SettingsC> {
    getSettings(): SettingsC {
        return {
            text: '',
        };
    }
}

class Factory {
    make<T extends SettingsEnum>(type: T): SettingsInterface<ConcreateSettings[T]> {
        switch (type) {
            case SettingsEnum.A:
                return new A();
            case SettingsEnum.B:
                return new B();
            case SettingsEnum.C:
            default:
                return new C();
        }
    }
}

const service = new Factory().make(SettingsEnum.B);
```

```
Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'SettingsInterface<ConcreateSettings[T]>'.
  The types returned by 'getSettings()' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'SettingsA' is not assignable to type 'ConcreateSettings[T]'.
      Type 'SettingsA' is not assignable to type 'SettingsA & SettingsB & SettingsC'.
        Type 'SettingsA' is missing the following properties from type 'SettingsB': r1, r2`
```

Who can explain me please why it happens and how I can resolve the problem?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73733862/18244921). It should apply to your problem as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
As I can see it is bid odd behaviour when I wrote twice the same method It would be ok if I had different arguments types but in my case... I don't know but it works and resolves my issue